# Is there any way to merge csv files directly when import into pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, merge

I have 35 csv files and i want to merge all the files together on 'Id' column. 
Is there any way to merge all? I can manually do like this by uploading each file and then defining into datafame

```
pd.merge(df_c1, df_c2, on='uuid')
```

But curious if there is any smart way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the fastest way to merge multiple csv files by column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140542/whats-the-fastest-way-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-by-column)

Comment: unfortunately not because i want to merge them on identical column "uuid"

Comment: What do you mean by _manually_ ? Can't you just use a loop? Please clarify what exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credit to @cs95 for [Pandas Merging 101](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

```
### read / create data frames
df_c1 = pd.DataFrame({'uuid': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'valueA': np.random.randn(4)})    
df_c2 = pd.DataFrame({'uuid': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 'valueB': np.random.randn(4)})
df_c3 = pd.DataFrame({'uuid': ['D', 'E', 'J', 'C'], 'valueC': np.ones(4)})

### list of data frames
dfs = [df_c1, df_c2, df_c3]
```

The following could then be used to `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df.set_index('uuid') for df in dfs], axis = 1) #.reset_index() could be used to make uuid a column again
```

Lastly, I could add to the solution by reading in multiple csv with something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import glob
import os

df_list = []

# note: this method assumes all of your csv files are in a single folder
path = '<insert your file path here>'

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))

for file in all_files:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file)
    df_list.append(df1)

concatenated_df = pd.concat([df for df in df_list], axis = 1) #note use axis = 0 to append row wise
```

Comment: Thanks. Its really stupid question but i am getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for for loop... I am really  unable to solve this

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. I missed an underscore in `all_files` when I initially wrote the for loop -- that may fix your issue if you copied it directly otherwise glad to help with more information